# Executing own Unix command in terminal?

Tags: unix, terminal, bash

I made an Unix command, macmac2unix, which converts Mac's Word file for Unix platforms.

I would like to run the command as

```
$macmac2unix file1 file2 file3 ...
```

**Problem:**
How can I run this command in every path?

I added the following to .bashrc unsuccessfully

```
CDPATH=:/Users/Sam/Documents/Unix
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? There's no need for a conversion in OSX - its text files use UNIX CRLFs.

Comment: You are confusing CDPATH with PATH. And I also ask, why are you doing this, or could you clarify what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Sam/Documents/Unix
```

to your .bashrc

Make your script executeable be sure it's located in /Users/Sam/Documents/Unix.
You could reread your .bashrc with:

```
~> . ~/.bashrc
```

But if you already played around with your enviroment variables a restart of your terminal
would be cleaner.

Comment: Hm, remove the line 5 and restart your terminal. Or try executing 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Sam/Documents/Unix' directly in your terminal for testing purposes.

Comment: It seems to work. I get the following error: -bash: /Users/Sam/Documents/Unix/macmac2unix: Permission denied

Comment: I get the program work by running:$ chmod +x macmac2unix . Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Add it to PATH, not CDPATH.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding it in PATH like this:

```
PATH=/Users/Sam/Documents/Unix:$PATH
```